# Storing different data types in a char array

Tags: c, arrays

I recently had a test question on how would you store an int, short, double into a char array and print out a int, short, and double from the array? This is what I did, but I had no other way to approach to question and was wondering if this was correct?

```
char something[14];
int a;
short b;
double c;
something[0] = a;
something[1]=b;
something[2] = c;
```

Comment: Your ints are all uninitialized so this assignment is undefined behavior. Did you want to store pointers to those ints instead? As it is right now, it's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I was going to store pointers but he didnt give us a pointer array to store it in he just gave us an char array with 14 indexes

Comment: Take account of the fact that (probably) `sizeof(short)` is 2,  `sizeof(int)` is 4,  `sizeof(double)` is 8, which sum to 14, the length of the array.

Comment: so to store something into the array it would be something[sizeof(int)] = a;?

Comment: Each array element can only store `char` value. So `short` needs 2 elements, `int` needs 4 elements, and `double` needs 8 elements.

Comment: yes even if you do that and do printf("%lf",somehting[sizeof(double)]); it wont print out the double

Comment: Is this even possible to do?

Comment: @cLax can you clarify is the array size (14) is part of the test question ?

Comment: I mean he originally stated that the array was of size(12) but insisted that it could be done in the question so I guess it could be done in a size(12) array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the intent was to do something like this.
(of course we should check that no buffer overflow occurs)

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
  char something[14];

  if(1) // store to something
  {
    int a=1234;
    short b=5678;
    double c=1234.5678;
    int offset=0;
    memcpy(something+offset, &a, sizeof(a));
    offset+=(int)sizeof(a);
    memcpy(something+offset, &b, sizeof(b));
    offset+=(int)sizeof(b);
    memcpy(something+offset, &c, sizeof(c));
    offset+=(int)sizeof(c);
  }

  if(1) // load from something
  {
    int a;
    short b;
    double c;
    int offset=0;
    memcpy(&a, something+offset, sizeof(a));
    offset+=(int)sizeof(a);
    memcpy(&b, something+offset, sizeof(b));
    offset+=(int)sizeof(b);
    memcpy(&c, something+offset, sizeof(c));
    offset+=(int)sizeof(c);
    printf("%d %hd %g\n", a, b, c);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Note that `memcpy()` is used here in order to be independent
from any alignment consideration.
If we assume that on a specific platform `a`, `b` and `c` have
respectively a 4-bytes, 2-bytes and 8-bytes size and alignment,
the corresponding bytes accessed inside the array thanks to
`memcpy()` could have any other alignment without any problem
(here they are simply packed).

```
              offset  0       4   6               14
  bytes in the array [a a a a|b b|c c c c c c c c]
```

Comment: *Note that I prefer `memcpy()` to assignment with cast because of potential alignment issues.*  `memcpy()` (or `memmove()`) is the only way to do this portably in conformance with the C standard.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes, that was the intent of my last sentence. Do you think it is unclear? Should I insert your comment?

Comment: I was just pointing out there's more than just a preference in play here.  Your wording could be read that the use of direct assignment is conforming, portable C code.

Answer (score 0):

Two option to consider, assuming size of array must be 14: memcpy and union

**Using memcpy**
Just copy the variables (after initialization, as needed) into the buffer, keeping a pointer to track position in buffer.

```
   char *p = something ;
   memcpy(p, &a, sizeof(a)) ; p += sizeof(a) ;
   memcpy(p, &b, sizeof(b)) ; p += sizeof(b) ;
   memcpy(p, &c, sizeof(c)) ; p += sizeof(c) ;
```

**Using struct**
Use 'struct' to combine the the values into continuous memory, and then a single copy into the array. Advantage is no need to track each field item sizeof, buffer position etc. Disadvantage is portability. Note that size may be different 32/64.

```
   struct { int v_a; short v_b ; double v_c ;} v = { .v_a=a, .v_b=b, .v_c = c};
   memcpy(something, &v, sizeof(something)) ;
```

Comment: The `struct` can be padded (size 16 here).

Comment: @WeatherVane you are correct. I'm still not sure if the array size (14) is a constraint, or part of the attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

An array variable in C is actually basically just a pointer to the first element of the array, and how the array is indexed depends on the pointer type.  So if it were, say, an `int []`, then `something[1]` is 4 *bytes* into the array assuming `sizeof(int) == 4` and so-on.

You can solve this problem, then, by a combination of pointer-arithmetic and type casting like so:

```
char something[14];
int a = 1;
short b = 2;
double c = 3.0;
*((int *) something) = a;
*((short *) (something + sizeof(int))) = b;
*((double *) (something + sizeof(int) + sizeof(short))) = c;
```

Though that's just one possible way.

Comment: `(int *) something`, and other casts are UB should `int, short,double` have stricter alignment requirements.  Also anti-aliasing may be of concern.

Comment: This is both a strict aliasing violation and potential undefined behavior for violating any alignment restrictions on data types.

Comment: The sequence `double`, `int` and then `short` would have better alignment.

Comment: Yes, in real code you wouldn't do this at all but for a homework/exam question this more clearly demonstrates the point that it's intended to be demonstrated I think, and will work on most compilers.

Comment: @WeatherVane No, because `something[]` can start anywhere.  And even if you constrain the alignment of `something[]` the code would still be a strict-aliasing violation.

Comment: but my whole question is how would you print out a double from the char array?

Comment: @cLax can you then please edit the question to say that?

Comment: @Iguananaut *and will work on most compilers*  [Only if your exposure to non-x86 systems is limited](https://www.google.com/search?q=sigbus+arm).